# MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies, and calling ambiguous functions

Tags: haskell, typeclass, functional-dependencies

With functional dependencies, I can declare the `Foo` class:

```
class Foo a b c | a -> b where
    foo1 :: a -> b -> c
    foo2 :: a -> c
```

and when I call `foo2`, everything works fine.  The compiler knows which instance to use because of the dependency.

But if I remove the dependency to create `Foo'`:

```
class Foo' a b c where
    foo1' :: a -> b -> c
    foo2' :: a -> c
```

everything still compiles fine, but now whenever I try to call `foo2'` GHC throws an error about not being able to resolve which instance to use because `b` is ambiguous.

Is it ever possible to call `foo2'` without error?  If so, how?  If not, why doesn't it generate a compilation error?

Comment: Neither should compile, the types of `foo1` and `foo2` imply different kinds for `a`. Did you mean `a -> b -> c` and `a -> c`?

Comment: @DanielFischer Whoops!  You're right.  It's fixed now.

Comment: `b` isn't reachable from `foo2'`, so the instance could only ever be determined if there was a direct way of specifying an instance to use. It might be possible with some `ConstraintKinds` wizardry, I don't know that, but I doubt it. So then, no, you can't ever call `foo2'`. Why it doesn't generate a compilation error, I don't know for sure, but I think it's that the compiler can't prove that you can never unambiguously call `foo2'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible to call `foo2'` in this context, because, as Daniel Fischer says, there is no way to determine which instance to use.  For example, if you had:

```
instance Foo' Int Int Int where
    foo2' x = x

instance Foo' Int Bool Int where
    foo2' x = x + 1
```

Both of these `foo2'`s have the same type signature, so there is no way to determine which one to call.

The usual way around this problem is to use a proxy:

```
data Proxy a = Proxy

class Foo'' a b c = where
    foo2'' :: Proxy b -> a -> c
```

Which you use like so to select which instance:

```
foo'' (Proxy :: Proxy Bool) 42
```

Comment: Thanks.  I just really wish ghc would say that `Foo2'` can't compile since it has code that can never be run.  Oh well.